# Why Enum.map is more efficient than Enum.count in Elixir?

Tags: performance, count, elixir

I've found that counting with `Enum.map |> Enum.sum` works much faster than `Enum.count`. But why is not the built-in count function efficient?

Compare these two lines:

```elixir
elements |> Enum.count(&check/1)
elements |> Enum.map(&(if check(&1), do: 1, else: 0)) |> Enum.sum
```

The results of tests with different length of list:

```
len   | map(), µs | count(), µs
===============================
   10 |      0.67 |    2.55
  100 |      5.52 |    8.91
 1000 |     59.00 |   73.12
10000 |    642.50 |  734.60
```

Source code: https://gist.github.com/artemrizhov/fc146f7ab390f7a807be833099e5cb83

```
$ elixir --version
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.1] [source-e7be63d] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Elixir 1.3.4
```

Comment: Is your code dependent on the performance of enumeration code?  Because unless it's really that important, this strikes me as optimization at the cost of comprehension.  I mean it's likely to be easier for anyone maintaining this code to figure out what you're doing with `Enum.count` versus `Enum.map |> Enum.sum`.  So unless the performance of this code is critical, I'd opt for the former.

Comment: Yes, my code is dependent on the performance of this function. I've created own count() function so that the code remains readable.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is because both `Enum.map/2` and `Enum.reduce/3` (that is used by `sum`) are heavily optimised for lists, while `Enum.count/2` has only a generic enumerable version.

To add to confusion, there's even a faster implementation:

```
elements |> Enum.filter(&check/1) |> Enum.count
```

On my machine, using modified benchmark you provided I get a consistent result of:

```
len = 10
map:    2.1706 μs
count:  7.0754 μs
filter: 1.9765 μs

len = 100
map:    19.921 μs
count:  27.579 μs
filter: 14.591 μs

len = 1000
map:    168.93 μs
count:  178.93 μs
filter: 163.43 μs

len = 10000
map:    2128.9 μs
count:  1822.1 μs
filter: 1664.6 μs
```

That said both the "map" and the "filter" version produce more garbage when they operate, so some of the time gains might be consumed by the extended garbage collection time. This is already visible in the benchmarks, as the relative gains between the versions decrease as the length of the length of the list (and the amount of intermediate garbage produced) increase.

EDIT: I submitted a PR that optimises the `Enum.count/2` function to be the fastest one https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/pull/5567

Comment: The up-to-date answer is that `Enum.count` is now faster, as it should be...

Comment: care to elaborate @Marc-AndréLafortune

Comment: The PR referred to in the "EDIT" has been merged, making the rest of the answer obsolete.